# Create a gradient for a turtle swarm

Tags: netlogo

I created a rectangular turtle grid using a total of 1000 turtles.

```
let in-shape patches with [ pxcor >= -50 and pxcor <= 50 and pycor >= -5 and pycor <= 5 ]
ask in-shape [ sprout 1 ]
```

Now I need to create a sort of **gradient**, that will give a sense of distance to my turtle swarm. Given a "**seed**" with value 0, it emits a message with its value 0 in a **certain talk_radius**. 
The turtles inside this **talk_radius** compute their distance to the seed. If the distance is less than a **fixed value** (called **gradient_distance**) the turtle will assume 1 as **gradient_value**, emitting a message with its value.
The other turtles do the same. So everyone will take the value x + 1, where x is the lowest value of the turtle within the **gradient_distance**, as shown in the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsjn9.png)

This is the relative algorithm in pseudo code:

```
loop
      if gradient seed = TRUE then // check if robot is designated as gradient source
     gradient value(self) = 0
  else
     gradient value(self) = GRADIENT MAX
     for all neighbors n do
        if measured distance(n) < G then // G represents the gradient-distance and GRADIENT MAX is infinity
           if gradient value(n) < gradient value(self) then
              gradient value(self) = gradient value(n)
     gradient value(self) = gradient value(self) + 1
  transmit gradient value(self)
```

And that's my implementation in netlogo:

```
globals [talk_radius gradient_max gradient_distance]
turtles-own [gradient_seed gradient_value]

to setup
  ca
  resize-world -60 60 -20 20
  crt 1000
  let in-shape patches with [ pxcor >= -50 and pxcor <= 50 and pycor >= -5 and pycor <= 5 ]
  ask in-shape [ sprout 1 ]
  set talk_radius 4
  set gradient_max 100000
  set gradient_distance 1
  ask turtles
  [set shape "circle"]

  ask turtles-on patch -50 5
  [set gradient_seed true]
end

to gradient-formation
while [true]
[
  ask turtles
  [
    ifelse (gradient_seed = true)
    [
      set gradient_value 0
    ]
    [
      set gradient_value gradient_max
      set color scale-color green gradient_value 0 120
      ask (other turtles) in-radius talk_radius with [distance myself <= gradient_distance] ;; i consider all the turtle in talk_radius having the right gradient_distance
      [
        let a ([gradient_value] of self) ;; "of self" is not necessary but helped me for a better comprehension
        if (a < ([gradient_value] of myself))
        [
          ask myself [set gradient_value a]
        ]
      ]
      set gradient_value (gradient_value + 1)
    ]
    set color scale-color green gradient_value 0 120

  ]

]
end
```

I used a scale-color in order to have a feedback of what i have done, as you can see in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLUYd.png). 
And now the problem: instead of **`let a ([gradient_value] of self)`**, i tried **`set a ([gradient_value] of self)`** adding **a** to the turtle variable (I added a in the turtle-own list on top). 
I thought the result would have been the same, but instead i got a **constantly increasing gradient_value** for every turtle as you can see in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vow1X.png)(the color white denotes a very high **gradient_value**).
Why this difference? 
 Thank you in advance and sorry for the long question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDITED EXTENSIVELY in response to discussion that refined the problem

First, I would like to start with a simpler version of the code. I believe this is exactly the same as yours without the `while[true]`. I removed the extra 1000 turtles you are creating, and separated the `ifelse` on whether a seed into two separate `ask` statements, for clarity. I also moved the colouring until after the value calculation is complete.

```
globals [talk_radius gradient_max gradient_distance]
turtles-own [gradient_seed? gradient_value]

to setup
  clear-all
  resize-world -60 60 -20 20
  let in-shape patches with [ pxcor >= -50 and pxcor <= 50 and pycor >= -5 and pycor <= 5 ]
  ask in-shape
  [ sprout 1
    [ set shape "circle"
      set gradient_seed? false
    ]
  ]
  set talk_radius 4
  set gradient_max 100000
  set gradient_distance 1

  repeat 10 [ gradient-formation ]
end

to gradient-formation
  ask turtles-on patch -50 5
  [ set gradient_seed? true
    set gradient_value 0
  ]
  ask turtles with [not gradient_seed?]
  [ set gradient_value gradient_max
    ask (other turtles) in-radius talk_radius with [distance myself <= gradient_distance]
    [ let my-gradval ([gradient_value] of self)
      if my-gradval < [gradient_value] of myself
      [ ask myself [set gradient_value my-gradval]
      ]
    ]
    set gradient_value (gradient_value + 1)
  ]

  ask turtles [set color scale-color green gradient_value 0 120 ]
end
```

There is a conceptual issue here. Until a turtle has its gradient_value calculated, it is 0. This means a large number of turtles will have a 0 turtle nearby and then have their own gradient_value as 1. It does not produce a colour gradient. To get around this, you need to run the gradient-formation several times. The approach in your code of `while [true]` introduces an infinite loop. Instead, you can `repeat` an arbitrary number of times (10 in the code above).

The problem with `let` versus `set` + `turtles-won` is that the `set` with turtles-own creates 1000 copies of gradient_value - one for each turtle. The `let` version creates a (temporary) global variable that all turtles access. So when you use `set`, you are setting it for that turtle, not as a general access number. I think what is happening is that the line `set gradient_value my-gradval` is accessing the wrong turtle's copy of my-gradval.

But, from the discussion, the purpose of the code that is causing the problem is to find a local minimum. There is a much more direct way of doing that.

```
to gradient-formation
  ask turtles-on patch -50 5
  [ set gradient_seed? true
    set gradient_value 0
  ]
  ask turtles with [not gradient_seed?]
  [ set gradient_value 1 + min [gradient_value] of 
      other turtles in-radius min (list talk_radius gradient_distance)
  ]

  ask turtles [set color scale-color green gradient_value 0 120 ]
end
```

**ADDED a minimum working example** to show the differences.

This is the `let` (global variable) version

```
turtles-own [testval]

to testme
  clear-all
  create-turtles 500
  [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set color blue
    set testval 1 + random 10
  ]
  ask one-of turtles
  [ set color red
    inspect self
    type "testval of asking turtle is " print testval
    ask turtles-on neighbors
    [ set color yellow
      let my-testval [testval] of self   ;; creates a temp global variable
      type "my-testval is " print my-testval
      if my-testval < [testval] of myself
      [ ask myself
        [ set testval my-testval        ;; copies the global variable value
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
end
```

This is the `set` (turtle attribute) version

```
turtles-own [testval my-testval]

to testme
  clear-all
  create-turtles 500
  [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set color blue
    set testval 1 + random 10
  ]
  ask one-of turtles
  [ set color red
    inspect self
    type "testval of asking turtle is " print testval
    ask turtles-on neighbors
    [ set color yellow
      set my-testval [testval] of self
      type "my-testval is " print my-testval
      if my-testval < [testval] of myself
      [ ask myself
        [ set testval my-testval    ;; copies value from one attribute to other
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
end
```

Comment: Thank you again for your answer JenB. Yes there is a single seed and you understood properly the exercise, but I didn't describe it well enough. Infact there is another thing to consider: I'm trying to simulate physical robots with limited capacities, so using the concepts of swarm intelligence I have to build up something decentralized.
I'm not allowed to use commands like max that are, let's say, "global". 
Your solutions were both correct, but they aren't decentralized. 
My solution works, if I use `let a`. I wonder why it doesn't with `set a`. I thought they worked the same in this case

Comment: If you want it to run the loop several times, then you need to put it into a `repeat` block or similar. I can't reproduce your problem with let/set. Before switching to the `min` version, I did `let my-gradval...` and added `my-gradval` to `turtles-own` and had no problems.

Comment: If I use `let my-gradval...` and put `my-gradival` in `turtles-own` then it says: "There is already a turtle variable called MY-GRADVAL".

Comment: Furthermore when in the setup procedure i call `gradient-formation` it is called one time, so the gradient isn't fully built and I had to put it in a `while[true]` loop. Is it correct?

Comment: yes, you either need `set` + `turtles-own`, or `let` without `turtles-own`. This is because `let' is both creating the variable and setting it to the value.

Comment: Yes, the gradient-formation procedure is only called once, this is why I said you would need to do something like `repeat 10 [gradient-formation]`. If you instead do this with `while [true]` then you simply introduce an infinite loop - it's not visible because the green colour gradient stabilises reasonably quickly. However, if you put in `tick` to advance the clock counter, you would see that ticks never stops increasing.

Comment: Ok, understood. But does `set` + `turtles-own` work when you run your code? When I try,  the `gradien_value` is miscalculated.

Comment: I think the answer now gives you sensible code and answers your question about `set` and `let`

Comment: The `set` and `let` thing is still not clear in my head. I tried a simple code: 
` to setup
  ca
  crt 1000
  ask turtles
  [
    let a 0
    set a a + 1
    show a
  ]
end`
I also tried with `set` and `turtles-own` instead. In both cases every turtle prints 1, so i thought `set` and `let` worked in the same way. But in the gradient code they work in a differently. I don't get it. 
PS sorry if i'm bothering you with all these messages.

Comment: If each turtle has an attribute my-gradval, then `ask myself [ set gradient_value my-gradval ]` goes to the `myself` turtle and tells it to copy the value stored in ITS variable named my-gradval (which is 0 if it's never been changed) to its variable named gradient_value. In contrast, in the `let` version of the code, the same statement copies the value from a GLOBAL variable that has been manipulated by the previous code. I will add a test piece of code to my answer to help you play with it.

Comment: YES!! I finally get it with your example, thank you so much.